# Rails install error build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using the Ruby version 2.7.2 and while installing rails I got these errors.

I used the ubuntu system.

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

So, please can anyone help me.

Thank you,
Neha

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo apt-get install cmake
bundle install
```